# how to sort prime factors into array and display in specific way using c code

Tags: c

Hi im trying to create a code using c language where you enter in a number it checks for its prime factors and then prints these factors out.
only there is a specific way that i am required to print these numbers

The prime factors of 56 are:
{2,7}

this is the required output and i can only get to this:

The prime factors of 56 are:
2,7,

ive been suggested to store the outputs into an array and then manipulate the array to delete the comma at the end and add the {} but im not sure how to do this.

Here is my code for reference:

```
#include<stdio.h> int main(){

int i, j, number, p;
printf("Enter a Number to find Prime Factors:");
scanf("%d", &number);
    if(number < 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
    }else {
printf("The prime factors of %d are:\n ", number);
for(i=2; i<=number; i++)
{
    /* Check 'i' for factor of num */
    if(number%i==0)
    {
        /* Check 'i' for Prime */
        p=1;
        for(j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                p = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        /* If 'i' is Prime number and factor of num */
        if(p==1)
        {
            printf("%d,", i);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well surely at least the opening `{` and closing `}` are easy to add. No? Just print those unconditionally before and after the `for` loop. As for the comma, one simple technique is to print it **before** the number except for the first time. So you simply need a flag which starts as true and then is set to false after the first number (or vice versa).

Comment: @kaylum That looks like an answer in a comment.

Comment: What is the required output for 4? {2} or {2,2}?

Comment: just the single 2 is required @Yunnosch

Comment: @kaylum, sorry, i kind of understand what you mean, but ive literally only being doing c coding for a very limited time so im no sure of what you exactly mean.

Comment: OK. Then you can turn kaylums comment into an answer yourself. Start with `printf(",%d", i);` and see what happens.

Comment: ive tried that but it just adds an extra comma before each output, ie ,2,,3,,4,
ive been told having to store the output factors ( 2 and 3 etc) into an array and then make another for loop telling that array that at the start it prints {3, and at the end it prints just the } but im not sure how to get the outputs into an array or manipulate that array

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you should indent your code consistently so that it is easy to read. In the following, I show you one way of doing what you want without using any intermediary array variables. The key points are that you need to distinguish the first number that you will output from the others, and you need to add curly braces unconditionally at the begin and the end.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

  int i, j, number, p;
  int first_factor = 1; /* Are we printing the first factor? */
  printf("Enter a Number to find Prime Factors:");
  scanf("%d", &number);

  if(number < 2)
  {
    printf("Invalid input\n");
  } else {
    /* I removed the line break in the printf below */
    printf("The prime factors of %d are: ", number);
    putchar('{'); /* Inconditionnaly prints '{' at the beginning of the answer */
    for(i=2; i<=number; i++)
    {
      /* Check 'i' for factor of num */
      if(number%i==0)
      {
        /* Check 'i' for Prime */
        p=1;
        for(j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
        {
          if(i%j==0)
          {
            p = 0;
            break;
          }
        }
        /* If 'i' is Prime number and factor of num */
        if(p==1)
        {
          if (first_factor == 1)
          {
            /* It is the first factor, prints without a comma */
            printf("%d", i);
            first_factor = 0; /* The other factors are not the first one */
          } else {
            printf(",%d", i);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    puts("}"); /* Inconditionnaly prints a '}' followed by a line-break */
  }
}
```